# CAST - The data types datetime and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I get the following error

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'  The data
>   types datetime and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator.

```
 <%
Set cnnSimple = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnSimple.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=P;DataSource=S\SQLEXPRESS; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxxx"

sql = "SELECT DISTINCT" & _
 "'<option value=""' + CAST([date_required] AS DATETIME) + '"">' + " & _
 "[date_required] + '</option>' " & _
  "FROM " & _
 "qryOutstandingPOLinesSource2 where supplier='" & suppliercode &"' and date_required < GETDATE()"

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sql, cnnSimple, 0, 1, 1

if rs.eof then
no_rows3 = true
else
str = rs.GetString()
End If
%>
```

Is there a workaround ? I have tried casting as `VARCHAR` and that didn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, printing out the SQL statement *after* variable substitution is helpful.

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=44988223-1f82-42b8-8334-c8d1600d24b4&tkw=similarities-and-differences-between-datetime-and-datetime2-data-types this might help you find the reason why it is not able to cast.

Comment: Your posted question does not show the use of `ADD` operator anywhere could you please update your question to show the actual problem code.

Comment: You'd be far better off putting this into a stored procedure. Also, is your code open to injection attacks?

Comment: First off you shouldn't be CASTing to a `DATETIME` as you are generating `VARCHAR` data *(string)*. If you change it to `CAST([date_required] AS VARCHAR(50))` for example do you get the same error or a different one? My guess is that error is a red herring because you are trying to do an incompatible `CAST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply cast your data to `NVARCHAR`, like so...

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT" & _
  "'<option value=""' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [date_required]) + '"">' + " & _
  "CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [date_required]) + '</option>' " & _
  "FROM " & _
  "qryOutstandingPOLinesSource2 where supplier='" & suppliercode &"' and date_required < GETDATE()"
```

Edited as per Lankmart's comment. The use of `CONVERT` instead of `CAST` will allow marginally better formatting abilities but is SQL Server specific, whereas you may find `CAST` is available in a wider range of T-SQL implementations.

Comment: It's usually better to use `CONVERT()` for date time formatting as you have more control over the outcome.

Comment: @Emma So it was that, I thought you said in your question you tried this already? *"I have tried casting as VARCHAR and that didn't work"*

Comment: @Lankymart Yes I did try VARCHAR initially and got another error - of course it was NVARCHAR I needed .. thanks for all your help and useful reply's - much appreciated... there's always some too quick to jump the gun and give bad rep - only asked a question ! :)

Comment: @Lankymart: very true - answer has been edited, but with the slight proviso that `CONVERT` is SQL Server specific, not T-SQL. Also, Emma, you can use `VARCHAR` as opposed to `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: @Paul - thanks - yes data will need some formatting but i'll worry about that on the next page... one step closer... help much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Emma: 'there's always some too quick to jump the gun and give bad rep' very true.

Comment: Thanks again both just trying the convert solution now.

Comment: @Paul :0)  see I'm not so bad after all

Comment: @Emma Would be interested in what error using `VARCHAR` give you as [Paul said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917754/cast-the-data-types-datetime-and-datetime2-are-incompatible-in-the-add-operato/31918028?#comment51749046_31918028) you should be able to use either. Personally though I tend to use `NVARCHAR` for everything as I do a lot of localisation stuff.

Comment: @Lankymart - It gives this error - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14' - The data types varchar and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator. BUT notice in my original question I only casted AS once, whereas in Pauls solution it's twice so that's probably where I was going wrong.

Comment: @Emma That will indeed be the issue, all outcomes need to be casted to strings *(`VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`)*, so the source data field is probably `DATETIME2`so it would fail as well as the `CAST([date_required] AS DATETIME)` which would return `DATETIME` would also fail.